# Can i send data from one website’s console to another?

Tags: html, post, get, console

So im trying to automate a task at work, and im wondering if theres anyway to send data from the console of one webpage to the console of another web page.

The task i am trying to automate consists of a website that has a prefilled form. I need to get elements from this form, and then copy them into another totally different website. Ive already written a script that pulls the data i need from the form and displays it in the console. Now I need to find a way to send the data (which is simply variables) to the other page’s console. Is this possible?

Keep in mind this is in a work computer, not allowed to download anything on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you an admin of the webpages and are these pages from the same site? if the answer is yes, i would recommend you use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for saving and retrieving the data then display it to the console.

If it's not your website and you want it to work anyway just create a simple browser extension.

Here are some links to help you get started with extensions
[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Build_a_cross_browser_extension)
[Chrome doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

> The idea is for you to target webpage A collect the data and post it to [Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist)
>   Then target webpage B to read data from your github gist and you dispaly it in the console.

Cheers, i hope it was helpfull

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, they are two different websites, and no I am not the admin. I think the solution lies in creating an extension, as you said. The extension would have to first pull the data from website A, and then input it into website B. Once the data is inputted into website B, it needs to go back to website A, ask for the next form, and repeat the process. Im unsure of how to make an extension go back and forth in extracting and inputting data between sites, is this possible? I was looking at the puppeteer extension, but Im not allowed to download anything.

Comment: Well i can see your idea but it's still hard for me to explain but i would love some analysis with you to figure out the best way to extract load and repeat if you have an algorithm then all that will be needed is to find the best way to implement it. I can think of scrapping web-page A for the forms input and loading the data scraped to website B repeatedly. I suggest we have a live chat to figure out something, i know it's not impossible i just need a clearer vision of what you are trying to achieve maybe a better case study or example of the intended result. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Which server side language are you using ?

Usually for these, you could just have a form which is posting data to another website's form.
Look at this php example :
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/retrieve-html-form-data-with-php/

Correct me If I did not understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Store the logs in following way
    console.stdlog = console.log.bind(console);
    console.logs = [];
    console.log = function(){
        console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
        console.stdlog.apply(console, arguments);
    }

    //copying the logs into a json file
    (function(console){

    console.save = function(data, filename){

        if(!data) {
            console.error('Console.save: No data')
            return;
        }

        if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

        if(typeof data === "object"){
            data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
        }

        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
            e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
            a    = document.createElement('a')

        a.download = filename
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
        e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
        a.dispatchEvent(e)
     }
    })(console)

    console.save(console.logs) //prints the logs in console.json file
```

//  from the console.json file, you can use log information from another page

Answer (score 1):

```
//Store the logs in following way
console.stdlog = console.log.bind(console);
console.logs = [];
console.log = function(){
    console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
    console.stdlog.apply(console, arguments);
}

localStorage.setItem('Logs', console.logs);
localStorage.getItem('Logs'); // from any browser
```

Comment: could you please explain the above code. i couldn't find any specific documentation. and am getting array of array logs in console.logs